# access different url but get same action in rails 4

Tags: url, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

i want access different url but get same action, example i access `http://127.0.0.1:3000/s/show` or `http://127.0.0.1:3000/show`, the url get same controller "store" and action "show". How do that?

how to typping in route?

thanks before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. In your `config/routes.rb` file:

```
get "s/show", to: "store#show"
get "show", to: "store#show"
```